# Solve facade root has not been set

Tags: laravel-5

I have uploaded my laravel app on cpanel so its showing this error when i try to visit the domain

Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /home/eswdistr/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:234 Stack trace: #0 /home/eswdistr/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(401): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('replaceNamespac...', Array) #1 /home/eswdistr/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(378): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->registerErrorViewPaths() #2 /home/eswdistr/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(293): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->renderHttpException(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException)) #3 /home/eswdistr/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(190): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpEx in /home/eswdistr/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 234

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not upload the vendor directory.

Ensure you have uploaded the vendor folder.